# 3 div inside a div (2 fixed height)

Tags: css, html

First of all, sorry for my bad english

My code http://jsfiddle.net/WsN3b/1/

```
<div id="header">
</div>
<div id="contentLeft">
</div>
<div id="contentRight">
    <div id="Content1">
        Title
    </div>
    <div id="Content2">
        Image
    </div>
    <div id="Content3">
        legend
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
</div>
```

As you can see, "Content3" is hidden because "Content2" takes too much space

I have to make my div "Content2" auto adjust and "Content1" and "Content2" take the size of its content.

My image has to take all the space it can.

I think I've forgot something to make it work, but I just can't find it...

Thanks

EDIT :

```
-----------------------------------
- Content 1                       - 50px
-----------------------------------
-                                 -
-                                 -
-                                 -
- Content 2                       - 100%
-                                 -
-                                 -
-                                 -
-----------------------------------
- Content 3                       - 50px
-----------------------------------
```

Comment: not understood your completely, but try removing `height : 100%;` from `#Content2` and set `#contentRight{background :#ff3}`

Comment: jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/WsN3b/3/

Comment: its something like this but i want "Content2" to have the size of "Content3" in your jsfiddle.net and "Content3" the size of "content1"

for example :
Content1 : 20px;
Content2 : maximum height;
Content3 : 20px;

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the bottom for contentRight

```
#contentRight {
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    right: 60%;
    background-color: #C63;
    overflow:visible;
}
```

See this http://jsfiddle.net/BxPpY/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you remove the height of #Content2 at that time height will adjust automatically depend on its content.

```
#header {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
height: 100px;
background-color: #abcdef;
}
#contentLeft {
position: fixed;
top: 100px;
bottom: 100px;
left : 40%;
right: 0;
background-color: #F63;
}
#contentRight {
position: fixed;
top: 100px;
bottom: 100px;
left: 0;
right: 60%;
background-color: #C63;
}
#footer {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
height: 100px;
background-color: #abcdef;
}

#Content1 {
background-color: #cc3;   
}

#Content2 {
background-color: #bb6;   
}

#Content3 {
background-color: #ff3;
}
```